# Does anybody know how to realize a delay until response come in Jmeter without using timer?

Tags: jmeter

I need to wait until response came, before next sample starts. Does any body know how to make it without timer(I don't know how much time I needed for each sampler respond)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jmeter executes requests sequentially. It waits for a response of first request to come before sending next request for a specified time.

if you want to wait for infinite time then you should set **response time out** to infinity

[image]